# IE10 following HTTP 302 redirect twice

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect

Im experiencing the following issue with IE10 (other browsers like Firefox, Opera, Chrome and older IE versions do not seem to be affected.

(1) The browser hits a page which responds with a HTTP 302 redirect to a different site (in order to perform a login):

**Request:**

```
GET https://www.domain-one.de/startpage.aspx?... HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: de-DE
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Host: www.domain-one.de
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: ...
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://login.domain-two.com/login?tid=hGZmFb77-9VyiwfkhIXIRMDp
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
P3P: CP="NOi CURa TAIa OUR NOR UNI"
Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2013 19:01:22 GMT
Content-Length: 190

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://login.domain-two.com/login?tid=hGZmFb77-9VyiwfkhIXIRMDp">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

(2) IE follows this redirect. The server sets some coookies and redirects back to the original site:

**Request:**

```
GET https://login.domain-two.com/login?tid=hGZmFb77-9VyiwfkhIXIRMDp HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: de-DE
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: login.domain-two.com
DNT: 1
Cookie: ...
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2013 19:01:22 GMT
Server: Apache
P3P: CP="NOI CURa TAIa OUR NOR UNI"
Location: https://www.domain-one.de/BackFromLogin.aspx?TID=hGZmFb77-9VyiwfkhIXIRMDp
Content-Length: 277
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://dwww.domain-one.de/BackFromLogin.aspx?TID=hGZmFb77-9VyiwfkhIXIRMDp">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

(3) Up to here, everything seems normal. However, IE10 now ignores the response just received and follows the same redirect again:

**Request:**

```
GET https://login.domain-two.com/login?tid=hGZmFb77-9VyiwfkhIXIRMDp HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: de-DE
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: login.domain-two.com
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: ...
```

This server detects this duplicate request and rejects it, responding with an error page (I know HTTP GET should be idempotent, but that is how this site works).

**It is beyond me why IE10 ignores the original response and issues the same request again (albeit without the 'Pragma: no-cache' header). Do you have any idea?**

Comment: Can you share a Fiddler capture which demonstrates this behavior? IE might do something like this if the response connection were RST before it was read, but that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution (after seeing your posting). It's described here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2691205

In my case, I was opening up a dialog (using jquery) that contained an iframe.  Instead of putting the src in the iframe (eg ), I added some javascript to the dialog popup

```
html = '<iframe id="myIframe">iframe not supported</iframe>';

$('#' + dialogId).append(html);
$('#' + dialogId).dialog({
title: 'SOME TITLE',
open: function () { $('#' + dialogId + 'iframe').attr('src', url); }  //IE10 HACK to     prevent double request!!!!

});
```